# css - when overriding on placeholder, border radius of input will get 0

Tags: css, input, placeholder

I want to override my inputs but input itself has its border-radius equals to 5px however when I use ::placeholder, it overrides the border.

```
input
{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input::placeholder
{
    background-color: #501950 !important;
}
```

Even I set border-radius to placeholder but no result :(

Comment: got confused. you want to override your input with what??

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour - which browser are you seeing this in? Setting a background colour on placeholder should have no effect on the border-radius of input. Are these styles in your example the actual styles you're using?

Comment: I have override input placeholder so the color has been changed. However input has no border-radius now :(

Comment: No, the complete one is like this: input::placeholder,
input::-moz-placeholder,
input::-webkit-placeholder,

Comment: i am able to see the border radius for the input box in chrome. which one you are testing?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai after you override input placeholder?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/11/

Comment: Set background of input to some color and check whether it removes radius or not!

Comment: iT STILL HAVE ` border-radius`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/15/

Comment: @Anuresh But placeholder goes over input

Comment: now what is your exact issue? i can able to see the border radius for input box Do you want the place holder also needs border radius? if yes, then just apply it. it will work.

Comment: I want the placeholder to have border-radius in order not to get out of input and not to change input style at the end.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/16/ check this out

Comment: @kodfire Can you put a fiddle or snippet here to produce the bug u r having?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/20/ it didn't!

Comment: @Anuresh https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/20/

Comment: @kodfire what didn't..what you mean by border radius. it is showing the curved border right. are you talking about the focus?????

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/22/ are you expecting this??

Comment: aha I got it, I think firefox v46 doesn't support it yet! is it correct?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai it doesn't have radius either in my browser

Comment: that is what my initial question..which browser?? i told it is coming in chrome

Comment: The OP's problem exists in FF, but not in Chrome. I don't know why it takes so many comments to finally say it. Also, border-radius on a placeholder does not work in FF. https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/46/